# Why I Get Double Column in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why do I get a double up of columns, as pictured:

[image]

How can I get this columns united to one column instead of 2 columns?

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
}

public class Woman : User
{
    public Woman()
    {
        s = new SharedManWoman();
        Clone = new Clone.CWoman();
    }

    public Clone.CWoman Clone { get; set; }
    public SharedManWoman s { get; set; }
}

public class Man : User
{
    public Man()
    {
        s = new SharedManWoman();
        Clone = new Clone.CMan();
    }

    public Clone.CMan Clone { get; set; }
    public SharedManWoman s { get; set; }
}

public class SharedManWoman
{
    [Key]
    public long tableId { get; set; }
}

public class CUser
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
}

public class CWoman : CUser {}

public class CMan : CUser {}
```

Comment: How is `Clone` defined?

Comment: i added please look again

Comment: @RufusL Clone is a property name, it is defined by CWoman and CMan

Comment: In your code above, the objects `CMan` and `CWoman` have no properties (except the `id` that they inherit from `CUser`. In the classes `Man` and `Woman`, there is a property called `Clone` that is of type `Clone.CMan` and `Clone.CWoman` respectively. Where is THAT type defined?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are defined in separate derived classes, and since they are navigation properties, they generate a foreign key for each:

```
public Clone.CWoman Clone { get; set; }

public Clone.CMan Clone { get; set; }
```

You could move these up to the base class instead and eliminate CWoman/CMan, instead making it of type CUser:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public Clone.CUser Clone { get; set; }

}
```

That should get rid of one of the duplicate FK's, but not sure if this solution fits in with what you are trying to accomplish though.